# Unreported SQL exception in the line 'ps=con.prepareStatement();'

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

I am working on a simple java web application that accepts data from user through a form and stores it in the SQL database through a servlet. Now when I write the code,Everything works fine but I get an error in the line where I write-

```
 str="insert into ..."
 ps= con.createStatement(str);   <-- Error here
 ps.executeUpdate();             <--error here
```

It says- Unreported SQL exception must be catch or thrown.

So,I surround the statement with try and catch block but now when i run the program i get this-
java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server] Could not find stored procedure str

I am stuck and can't find a solution anywhere. I have created the database and the table and the values get inserted through SQL Query. I have created a User DSN named 'mydata' through odbcad32 as well.
Please help me out!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String type="",name="",pw="",city="",country="",contact="",sal="";
    type=request.getParameter("ddltype");
    name=request.getParameter("txtname");
    pw=request.getParameter("txtpwd");
    city=request.getParameter("txtcity");
    sal=request.getParameter("txtsal");
    country=request.getParameter("txtcountry");
    contact=request.getParameter("txtcontact");
    try {
        conn();
        String str="insert into details values('"+type+"','"+name+"','"+pw+"','"+city+"','"+country+"','"+contact+"','"+sal+"')";
        ps=con.prepareStatement("str");
        ps.executeUpdate();

        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet regsev</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body> INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet regsev at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    } 
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        out.print(""+e);
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

Comment: Can you add your full code here (or as much as possible).

Comment: Also see the importance of enough code posting: Your abstract (**ps= con.createStatement(str);**) was different then the real code.

Comment: Haha! I am sorry this was my first time.

Comment: No worries. Fun fact: You corrected one of your problems by creating your abstract code (no quotes around str).

Comment: Haha! I know right! subconscious mind ahoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many remarks here.

```
   String str="insert into details values('"+type+"','"+name+"','"+pw+"','"+city+"','"+country+"','"+contact+"','"+sal+"')";
   ps=con.prepareStatement("str");
   ps.executeUpdate();
```

All 3 incorrect.
Prepared statements are to help performance (in most cases), simplify code and prevent SQL injection.
Your code does not do 2 out of 3.

Below a sample of how it should be:

```
   String str="insert into details (type, name,pwd ) 
    values(?,?,?)";
   ps=con.prepareStatement(str); // so no "" around str.
   ps.setString(1,type); // Sets the content of the first ?, all safe against SQL Injection
   ps.setString(2,name); // Sets the content of the second ?
   ps.setString(3,pwd); // Sets the content of the third ?
   ps.execute(); // Execute instead of executeUpdate.
```

The database can now also re-use the prepared statement execution plan, saving you a few 100s of a second insert.

Comment: Oh my god! I just didn't notice the blunder. The " " around str. Thank you so much and Sorry! :)

Comment: @AakankshaPandey: There are more problems than just the double quotes around `str`.  The example in this answer is not vulnerable to SQL Injection. The original code is vulnerable. This example doesn't call `createStatement`. The original code calls `createStatement` with an invalid parameter. All of the remarks in this answer are pertinent.

Comment: Yeah I saw that too. But the 'exception' in my code was due to the blunder I did. (i.e the double quotes!)
Anyway,I'll keep this in my mind. Thank you for your valuable inputs. :)